# Why I can't used php curl that I generate from Postman in my project?

Tags: api, web-services, postman, php-curl

I sent request with attached csv file by postman . I got the right

response from web service .

[image]

but when I generated php curl from postman to my project with upload file

form . I got error from the response . It seemed Web service can received

csv file but It can't use the file because Web service returned message

"Upload salesquote fail" not "No attached file part" . This error message

look like when I attached empty csv file . but I'm not sure.

[image]

this is my code

```
    if ( isset($_FILES["salesquote2"])) {
      $url = <service URL>;
      $filename = $_FILES['salesquote2']['name'];
      $filedata = $_FILES['salesquote2']['tmp_name'];
      $filesize = $_FILES['salesquote2']['size'];
      $storefile = __DIR__."/csvfile"."/".$filename;
      $storefile2 = realpath($filedata);
      echo '$filename = ' . $filename . "</br>";
      echo '$filedata = ' . $filedata . "</br>";
      echo '$filesize = ' . $filesize . "</br>";

      enter code hereecho $storefile . "</br>" ;



      $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "4546",
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"salesquote\"; filename=\"$filedata\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Postman-Token: 56363463-ed09-4cf0-bb91-ff546980bb98",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
}
```

Comment: I moved upload file from tmp to directory and attached file from that directory but  It doesn't work  the same .